# I get a type error and I don't know why

Tags: haskell

I have this code but this error is showing up and I don't know why:

```
Couldn't match type 'Char' with '[Char]'
    Expected type: [String]
      Actual type: String
    In the return type of a call of 'tarefa'
    In the first argument of 'unlines', namely '(tarefa (lines inp))'
    In the first argument of 'putStrLn', namely
      '(unlines (tarefa (lines inp)))'



main = do inp <- getContents; putStrLn (unlines (tarefa (lines inp)))

tarefa :: [String]-> String
tarefa tab = let board = getBoard tab 
                 valid = valBoard board 
                 ym = length board
                 xm = length (head board)
                 (r:p:s) = drop (length board) tab
             in if valid/=0 then [show valid]                   
                            else if not (coordOK xm ym r)
                                 then [show (ym +1)]
                                 else if not (progOK p)
                                      then [show (ym+2)]
                                      else if s /= []
                                           then [show (ym+3)]
                                           else ["OK"]
```

Comment: unlines has type `[String] -> String`

Answer (score 4):

`unlines` expects a list of Strings, which it will join together with `'\n'` characters. `tarefa`'s type declaration, however, says it returns a single String.

Looking at your implementation it looks like `tarefa` is meant to return a list of strings; I think you just need to fix the type declaration to reflect that.

Type errors involving Strings can be confusing because `String` is a type synonym for `[Char]` and the compiler isn't consistent about which one it refers to in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Two questions:

1. What do you think is the type of this expression:

   ["OK"]

(Hint: You can ask ghci)?

2. Why, then, are you claiming that your function returns a `String`?